Binding Image and text in button Style
I've created a button style consisting of an image and text:
 <Style x:Key="Btn_Macros" TargetType="Button" >
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="100"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource ButtonFocusVisual}"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource App_Foreground}"/>
    <Setter Property="TextElement.FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2,2,2,2"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Grid x:Name="Grid">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Border Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{StaticResource NormalBorderBrush}"/>
                    <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="/icons/tree_view_line_Blanc.png" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
                    <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="center" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            ......
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

I can change the text when implementing the button
<Button Style="{StaticResource Btn_Macros}" Content="Gravures"   Click="Button_LaunchGravure_Click"/>

but I can't change the image source.
Can you help me?

I want to set the image source in the button implementation along with the content

